# Cannot update field value with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have been struggling with updating the value contained inside a paragraph of my page using Vue.js. Indeed as you can see below , in the axios statement of the vueLog Vue, I am trying to put a message "Welcome *username*" in the *{{loggeg_in_msg}}* field that is contained in my nav. ( I am getting this username from a get request using the access token that I stored in my cookies).

I actually placed a console.log in the **then()** statement to see whether I was attributing the proper value and it is returning the expected value. Then there must be a mistake with the this I am binding but I cannot see what I am having wrong.

Here are the snippets:

**nav.html**

```html
<div th:fragment="nav" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns">
            <ul class="navMenu">
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="/categories">Categories</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <p id="loggedIn">{{logged_in_msg}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head th:replace="fragments/header :: header('Home')" />
<body>
<div id="root">
    <div th:replace="fragments/nav :: nav"></div>
    <div Class="container"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="twelve columns">
                <h1>HKEstate</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li v-for="post in posts">
                        <h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
                        <p>{{post.body}}</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<div th:replace="fragments/footer :: foot"></div>
<script>
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data : {posts: []},
    mounted(){
        this.fetchPosts();
    },
    methods: {
        fetchPosts(){
            axios.get("/posts").then(function(response){
                this.posts = response.data;
            }.bind(this));
        },
        getLink(post){
            return '/post/' + post.id;
        }
    }
});
</script>
</html>
```

**footer.html**

```html
<div th:fragment="foot" th:remove="tag">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/script.js"></script>
</div>
```

**script.js**

```js
function getCookie(name) {
    var value = "; " + document.cookie;
    var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
    if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}

function isAnonymous(name){
    return name == "anonymousUser";
}

var vueLog = new Vue({
    el : "#loggedIn",
    data : {logged_in_msg : ""},
    mounted(){
        var isLoggedIn = false;
        if(!(getCookie("access_token")==null)){
            axios.get("/getUsername?access_token=" + getCookie("access_token"))
                .then(function(response){
                    this.logged_in_msg = "welcome "+response.data;
                    console.log(this.logged_in_msg)
                }.bind(this))
                .catch(function(error){
                    console.log("OK3:"+error.stack )
                    //TODO delete cookie?
                }.bind(this));
        }
    }
});
```

So far when I am inspecting my page all that I am having is an empty paragraph

. Is there anything that I missed?

Comment: Are you using a promise library (like bluebird)?.  Try removing `.bind(this)` from your code. The fetchPosts() method at least should work without it.

Comment: Hi Juan, Thx for your help! The fetchPost() is working fine the statement causing me problem is the one linked to the axios.get("/getUsername?access_token=" + getCookie("access_token")) statement. With or without binding it is the same. No promise library, what is its purpose?

Comment: hey, sorry for the confusion! What does this line show: `console.log(this.logged_in_msg)`?
Try declaring the data option as a function: `data: function () { return { logged_in_msg: '' }}`. You are not changing it anywhere else, but that is the proper way to do it.

Comment: It looks like removing the Vue that is in the js of my htlm page is solving the issue. Would it be possible that the 2 Vue are conflicting each other?. for the console.log , it is returning the expected value.(thanks for the best practice advise)

Comment: @Pclaverie Regarding your question here, notice that your `nav` is nested within `root` and that you have two separate Vue instances for both. This is bad. `new Vue` should only ever be called for the absolute root element, never for a child element. If you want to have separate code for a child element, please consider looking into creating a reusable `component` via `Vue.component('component-name', {options})`. You can read more about this in the Vue documentation: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html